# Make image from Silverlight control with embedded html

Tags: html, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How to make image from Silverlight control with embedded html. Html was embedded with HtmlPage help. Currently in image i see empty space, where have to be html content. I know that html is rendered in absolute positioned div over silverlight plugin.

> Image proxyImage = new Image();
>   proxyImage.Source = new
>   WriteableBitmap(Application.Current.RootVisual,
>   Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderTransform);

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in your answer "over silverlight plugin".  Silverlight does not have access to the image that the browser renders over the image.  It can only see the surface that it is rendering.